# Loading all modules in a folder

Tags: react-native

After figuring out how to achieve this in a web application using WebPack (https://medium.com/@janos.jarecsni/auto-loading-modules-c8c47472d59b) I was quite sad to see that it is impossible to do in React Native.

I think being able to load all modules in a folder is a rather key technique (this way your code does not have to know about the individual modules), and so it is rather limiting in React Native.

Anyone knows if this is possible using some arcane ways, or any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: Have you tried using https://github.com/callstack-io/haul

Comment: No, thanks for mentioning! As it's based on WebPack the require.context should work there, will take a good look (also considering using Expo for now). thanks!

Comment: Please vote: https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/load-all-modules-from-a-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to achieve this, I have written an article to discuss this in detail. The good news is that there is a Babel plugin that allows you to do this.

https://medium.com/@janos.jarecsni/auto-loading-modules-c8c47472d59b

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import all the modules in the current dir, you can try this one.

- `import_cur_modules` only imports modules in the current dir,
- `import_sub_modules` imports all the modules including sub dirs in the current dir

**Note: This function only returns the import lines that need be executed in the `__init__.py` in the current dir.**

```py
import_lines = import_sub_modules(os.path.dirname(__file__))
for line in import_lines:
    exec(line)
```

```py
import os


def import_cur_modules(base_dir: str):
    """import modules in the current dir
    Note: This function only returns the import lines that need be executed in the `__init__.py` in base_dir
    """
    import_lines = []
    for name in os.listdir(base_dir):
        if name.endswith('.py') and name != '__init__.py':
            import_lines.append(f"from . import {name[:-3]}")
    return import_lines


def import_sub_modules(base_dir: str):
    """import all the modules including sub dirs in the current dir
    Note: This function only returns the import lines that need be executed in the `__init__.py` in base_dir
    """
    import_lines = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(base_dir):
        root = os.path.relpath(root, start=base_dir)
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith('.py') and name != '__init__.py':
                path_units = os.path.join(root, name[:-3]).split('/')
                if path_units[0] == '.':
                    path_units.pop(0)
                import_lines.append(
                    f"from .{'.'.join(path_units[:-1])} import {path_units[-1]}"
                )
    return import_lines
```